# Read Excel Files and put the data into 3 column and save into the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I wanted to create a Web API  where it can read the excel file has more than 5 columns and convert the tables into 3 columns and later on saved into the database.

Anyone knows how do I start? I'm new to Web API?

Thank you

Comment: Please look at web api development docs first. To answer the question, where is the file coming from , are you going to upload it ? or is it stored in azure blob, aws s3 etc ? where is this api going to run ? how big is the file ? - it determines where you want to execute your parsing logic. who will consume this web api?  answer these questions and you may have more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

For reading excel, you may try to use the ExcelDataReader.

Go in to NuGet in Visual Studio and search for ExcelDataReader
Or on GitHub: https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader

Comment: how should i read the excel files? Do I need to add an upload button in cshtml file in from Visual Studio?